# accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath returning undesired indexPath in Swift 2

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2, accessoryview

I have a `UITableViewController` populated with `NSManagedObjects` from an `NSFetchRequest` called in `viewDidLoad`.

Everything works as desired on the `myTableViewController` with the exception of `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath`, which returns `indexPath` 0.

Here's how I'm implementing `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("reorderSequences", sender: UIButton())
}
```

Here's my `performSegueWithIdentifier`:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "reorderSequences" {
            // Get a hold of the item to send to the destinationVC
            let button = sender as! UIButton
            let hitPoint = button.convertPoint(CGPointZero, fromCoordinateSpace: self.tableView)
            if let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint) {
                // ** Regardless of which accessoryButton I press, the indexPath 
                // for index 0 is always the value **
                print("\nhitPoint's x: \(hitPoint.x)\n hitPoint's y: \(hitPoint.y)")
                let selectedThingSequence = self.thingSequences[indexPath.row] 
                print("prepareForSegue's indexPath is \(indexPath)")
            // set up the segue
                let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ReorderTableViewController
                destinationVC.thingSequenceToReorder = selectedThingSequence
                print(controller.description)
            }
        }
    }
```

My understanding is using the `UIButton` as the sender lets me figure out which `indexPath` the sender lives in `performSegueWithIdentifier`. Obviously, that's not the case. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

For every easy question, there's a easy answer:

In `prepareForSegue` I made `indexPath` the `sender`, like so:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("reorderThings", sender: indexPath)
}
```

In `prepareForSegue`, I got a hold of the indexPath that was passed like so:

```
let indexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath
```

If you're running a bunch of segues, you want to be careful. For my purposes, it works. Thank you to Tom Harrington for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("reorderSequences", sender: UIButton())
```

You are not sending "the" `UIButton`. You're creating a brand-new instance of `UIButton`. It's not the one you tapped. It's not on the screen or in the view hierarchy anywhere. It has default values for everything. So when you get to performing the segue, there's no useful information in the incoming `UIButton`, and you get the same result every time.

Comment: I see. Can I make the sender the `indexPath` and once it gets to `prepareForSegue`, do `indexPath = sender` and get on down the road?

Comment: As long as you're careful about handling `sender` in other cases where the segue would be triggered, sure.